# WXPython becoming unresponsive during youtube download with Pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, wxpython, pytube

I Am New In wxpython.
I am Making Program using the pytube library.
I can download youtube videos just fine on its own, but when I put it in the WXPython method, the UI suddenly hangs and becomes unresponsive. But When The Video finnished downloading, the UI is responsive again.
This Is My Code.

```
import wx
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
import os
import time
from threading import Timer as wait
from accessible_output2 import outputs
say=outputs.auto.Auto()
speak=say.speak
app = wx.App()
class abhishek(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, -1, title = 'ar-developers YouTube Downloader, 1.2.')
        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Center()
        vid = wx.Button(self.p, -1, 'Download Video...')
        vid.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.video_download)
        aud = wx.Button(self.p, -1, 'Download Audio...')
        aud.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.audio_download)
        pv = wx.Button(self.p, -1, 'Download Playlist...')
        pv.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.playlist_download)
        pa = wx.Button(self.p, -1, 'Download Playlist in Audio Format...')
        pa.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.playlist_audio_download)
        self.Show()
    def on_progress(self, stream=None, chunk=None, bytes_remaining=None):
        self.x = '%'
        self.total_size = self.video.filesize
        self.bytes_downloaded = self.total_size - bytes_remaining
        self.liveprogress = int(self.bytes_downloaded / self.total_size * 100)
        speak(f"downloading, {self.liveprogress} {self.x}")
        time.sleep(2)
    def video_download(self, event):
        url = wx.GetTextFromUser('Type the URL of your video', 'URL')
        try:
            youtube = pytube.YouTube(url,on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox('Please enter a valid URL', 'Alert')
            exit()
        speak(f'downloading, {youtube.title}')
        self.video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        self.video.download("Downloads")
        wx.MessageBox('Download Complete!', 'Complete')
    def audio_download(self, event):
        url = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter URL of Your Video", "URL")
        try:
            divi = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox('Please Enter a Valid URL','Error')
            exit()
        speak(f'downloading, {divi.title}')
        self.video = divi.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        self.out_file = self.video.download("Downloads")
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(self.out_file)
        self.new_file = base + '.mp3'
        os.rename(self.out_file, self.new_file)
        wx.MessageBox('Download Complete!', 'Complete')
    def playlist_download(self, event):
        url = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter the URL of your playlist. ", "URL")
        try:
            playlist = Playlist(url)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox('Please Enter a Valid URL','Error')
            exit()
        speak('Please Wait, While We Are Downloading Your Play List')
        for p in playlist.video_urls:
            f = pytube.YouTube(p,on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
            speak(f'downloading, {f.title}')
            self.video = f.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            self.video.download("Downloads")
    def playlist_audio_download(self, event):
        url = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter URL of your playlist", "URL")
        try:
            playlist = Playlist(url)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox('Please Enter a Valid URL','Error')
            exit()
        speak('Please Wait, While We Are Downloading Your Play List')
        for p in playlist.video_urls:
            f = YouTube(p, on_progress_callback=self.on_progress)
            speak(f'downloading, {f.title}')
            self.video = f.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
            self.out_file = self.video.download("Downloads")
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(self.out_file)
            self.new_file = base + '.mp3'
            os.rename(self.out_file, self.new_file)
abhishek()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a general issue. Not only in wx the not responding issue is happening in tkinter too. But it happens when you run the code after compiling to an exe file.